# How to change background color of box?

Tags: jquery

What im trying to do is when user click on box it change background color of that box, but also to remove background color of previous box.

I manage to get selected box that i click but previous selected is also.So i want to remove previous selected box and get seleceted only that i click.
This is my fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/pmadwvpk/

```
$(".left-sidebar-box").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#2f3d46");
});
```

Comment: use `$(this).css("background-color", "#2f3d46");`

Comment: Create some `active` class and append it on the `box` click, while removing it on the rest of the boxes.

Comment: As simple as this
`$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code to this:

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/pmadwvpk/3/

JS:

```
$(".left-sidebar-box").on("click", function() {
    $(".left-sidebar .left-sidebar-box.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

CSS:

```
.left-sidebar .left-sidebar-box.active {
    background: #2f3d46
}
```

Comment: `$(".active").removeClass("active");` will remove all the `active` classes - what if there will be more? I'd use `$(".left-sidebar-box.active")` to target explicitly that menu links.

Comment: @Vucko Modified that selector.

Answer (score 2):

Update fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pmadwvpk/1/

Code

```
$(".left-sidebar-box").on("click", function() {
    $(".left-sidebar-box").css("background","");
    $(this).css("background", "#2f3d46");    
});
```